# Standard safe type check?

Tags: c++, rtti

In my `IsSame` function I would like to return `true` if both pointers are pointing to objects of the same **type**. So only the middle call should return `true`. `D1` and `B` shouldn't be considered the same.

The below seems to be exactly what I want but is it safe according to the standard?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class B { virtual void foo() {} };
class D1 : public B { };
class D2 : public B { };
class D3 : public B { };

bool IsSame(B*a, B*b) {
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return false;
    return *(intptr_t*)a == *(intptr_t*)b;
}

int main() {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    D1 d1b;
    B b;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", IsSame(&d1, &d2), IsSame(&d1, &d1b), IsSame(&d1, &b));
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 0
```

Comment: The code doesn't even make sense. Why the defeferencing?

Comment: What's the point in converting to `intptr_t*`?

Comment: @GManNickG: Because I need a `==` operator. That cast is so I can compare the ptr value like an int. But whatever size a ptr is (thus why it isn't int*)

Comment: I guess you are trying to see if the two objects point to the same vtable? This is definitely not standard.

Comment: @user315052: Thats exactly what I am doing. I'm not sure why this isn't but if you can point where or tell me how to check then i'll accept ;)

Comment: @acidzombie24: "That cast is so I can compare the ptr value like an int" Then you would cast to `intptr_t`, not `intptr_t*`. But the result of this conversion is implementation-defined anyway, and all you can do reliably is cast it back to the original value.

Comment: Can't you just use `std::is_same<decltype(d1), decltype(d2)>::value` (and similarly for the others)?

Comment: Once you realize the need to decide whether a `const T*` is the same type as a `T` or `volatile T*` (or, perhaps a `const U*` where `U` is a subclass of `T`), you're probably better off using std::type_traits ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/ ; C++11) or the equivalent Boost library.

Comment: @Praetorian: Doesn't seem to work. decltype(var) and decltype(*var) seem to get true which isn't what I am excepting

Comment: @MaxLybbert: Is there a version that considers base and derive types not the same?

Comment: @acidzombie24: Both of them missed that you're trying to do dynamic type lookup. Those solutions only work at compile-time, with the static type.

Comment: you have `std::is_same` if you want the types to be exactly the same, `std::is_convertible` or `std::is_base_of` if you want to deal with cases where one pointer is convertible to another.  You can wrap them in a function if you don't want to put the types in angle brackets:  `template<typename T, typename U> bool IsSame(T* t, T* u) { return std::is_same<T, U>::value; }` which can be called as `IsSame(foo, bar);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to see if the two objects have the same v-table. The C++ standard does not speak to the presence of a v-table pointer, let alone where it would be in an object's layout. So, your solution is trivially non-standard, and the behavior of your program is in fact undefined.

If you want to see if the two base pointers have the same derived type but without RTTI, you will need some mechanism to let you know the id of a derived type. This likely means a virtual method that returns an id that all the derived types have to implement.

Comment: Its a shame the standards don't specific a way to get the vtable ptr.

Comment: @acidzombie24, as user315052 indicated, the point is that the standard doesn't say that a C++ implementation must use v-tables to implement virtual methods: it is the most common mechanism, but not the only way to do it. Consequently, the standard cannot possibly specify how to get a v-table pointer - there might not be one at all. The solution proposed by user315052 is probably the sanest one and it's what I would do. There is such a thing as trying to be too clever.

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work:

```
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>

class B { virtual void foo() {} };
class D1 : public B { };
class D2 : public B { };
class D3 : public B { };


template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool is_same(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) {
  return typeid(t1) == typeid(t2);
}

bool is_same_no_template(const B& b1, const B& b2) {
  return typeid(b1) == typeid(b2);
}

int main(){
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    D1 d1b;
    B b;
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha
             <<"d1 == d2  ? "<<is_same(d1, d2)<<std::endl
             <<"d1 == d1b ? "<<is_same(d1, d1b)<<std::endl
             <<"d1 == b   ? "<<is_same(d1, b)<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"No Template"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<std::boolalpha
             <<"d1 == d2  ? "<<is_same_no_template(d1, d2)<<std::endl
             <<"d1 == d1b ? "<<is_same_no_template(d1, d1b)<<std::endl
             <<"d1 == b   ? "<<is_same_no_template(d1, b)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc 4.7.2 I get the following output:

```
[Prompt] g++ example.cpp -std=c++11
[Prompt] ./a.out
d1 == d2  ? false
d1 == d1b ? true
d1 == b   ? false
No Template
d1 == d2  ? false
d1 == d1b ? true
d1 == b   ? false
```

Beware that this code will not compile if you decide to compile without "run-time type information" (RTTI; the `-fno-rtti` compile flag in gcc).

Comment: You're using templates so `T1` and `T2` match at compile-time, so the purpose of `typeid` is really lost here. (This is why I deleted my answer.) You should match the question and only have `B*`'s at the time of comparison.

Comment: @GManNickG, @acidzombie24: I'm afraid I don't understand ;( (sorry, beginner here). What about the version without templates? Also, could you elaborate on why is the purpose of `typeid` lost?

Comment: @acidzombie24: I deleted my answer because it had the same misinformation this answer has. This answer misses the point entirely by using the objects directly, so it has the types directly in the template arguments. I revised by answer to demonstrate the solution fully using dynamic lookup.

Comment: @GManNickG: Your answer is good. I was just trying to figure out if typeid works when i disable runtime information. Why did you delete your answer? oh right i thought you use B* not templates. -edit- damn, I didnt edit in time

Comment: @Arrieta: You're using `d1` and `d2` directly, so the type `D1` and `D2` is known directly at compile-time. There's no need for `typeid` here, then. The point of the question was that we only have `B*` to work with and need to do the type-lookup dynamically. I made the same mistake, don't feel bad. You need to do what my answer does and work with `B*`'s before you do any further type checks. Your version without templates is more along the point, yes.

Comment: @acidzombie24: `typeid` won't work without RTTI. This entire thing is impossible without it. If you disable RTTI, you truly lose the type information and would have to emulate RTTI yourself.

Comment: @GManNickG: I'm unsure if I want to disable RTTI or not, but i know my original code works without RTTI

Comment: Is there a case where the no-template code would work and the template code would not? I'm still trying to get my head around this...

Comment: @Arrieta: You're good. The template code will always work where the no-template code will, it just has extra information (deduced static type versus specified static type).